# I'm new to SQL and thinking is there any way to simplify this Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, redash

Im really new to SQL, doing this for my basic needs for works and basically I'm not a tech guy. But I'm curious to know is there any way to simplify my SQL Code here:

```
SET sql_mode = '';


SELECT DISTINCT partner.kode_agent,
                institusi.nama,
                count(proposal.kode_proposal) AS 'Jumlah Proposal',
                sum(project.jumlah_pencairan) AS 'Jumlah Pencairan'
FROM brw_proposals proposal
JOIN ms_agent partner ON proposal.kode_agent = partner.kode_agent
JOIN ms_agent_institusi institusi ON partner.kode_institusi = institusi.kode_institusi
JOIN ms_projects project ON proposal.kode_proposal = project.kode_proposal
WHERE institusi.nama like 'BMT%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 4
  OR institusi.nama like 'BMT%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 8
  OR institusi.nama like 'BMT%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 3
  OR institusi.nama like 'BMT%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 10
  OR institusi.nama like 'Baitul Maal Wat%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 4
  OR institusi.nama like 'Baitul Maal Wat%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 8
  OR institusi.nama like 'Baitul Maal Wat%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 3
  OR institusi.nama like 'Baitul Maal Wat%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 10
  OR institusi.nama like 'Ksp%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 4
  OR institusi.nama like 'Ksp%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 8
  OR institusi.nama like 'Ksp%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 3
  OR institusi.nama like 'Ksp%' and proposal.status_proposal_id = 10
GROUP BY institusi.nama
```

Cause I guess it's too much with the WHERE clause and I'm not so familiar with subquery.

Hope anyone can share their experience to improve my code! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You have `GROUP BY institusi.nama` but are selecting both `partner.kode_agent` and `institusi.nama,` - which  `partner.kode_agent` are you hoping to get if there is more than one in a group?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplified query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT partner.kode_agent,
                institusi.nama,
                count(proposal.kode_proposal) AS 'Jumlah Proposal',
                sum(project.jumlah_pencairan) AS 'Jumlah Pencairan'
FROM brw_proposals proposal
JOIN ms_agent partner ON proposal.kode_agent = partner.kode_agent
JOIN ms_agent_institusi institusi ON partner.kode_institusi = institusi.kode_institusi
JOIN ms_projects project ON proposal.kode_proposal = project.kode_proposal
WHERE (institusi.nama like 'BMT%' OR institusi.nama like 'Ksp%' OR institusi.nama like 'Baitul Maal Wat%') and proposal.status_proposal_id IN (4,8,3,10)
GROUP BY institusi.nama
```

You can use `IN` clause to match muliple values like

```
proposal.status_proposal_id IN (4,8,3,10)
```

Comment: You can go one step further with `institusi.nama REGEXP '^BMT|^Ksp|^Baitul Maal Wat'`

Comment: The query will only be optimized, when all indexes that are needed to make this query performant are in place...... This answer only gives a shorter version of the original query.

Comment: @Luuk He mentioned in the question; he wanted to simplify the SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a valid query. There isn't enough information to say whether or not it satisfies your requirements...

```
SELECT p.kode_agent
     , i.nama
     , COUNT(k.kode_proposal) 'Jumlah Proposal'
     , SUM(j.jumlah_pencairan) 'Jumlah Pencairan'
  FROM brw_proposals k
  JOIN ms_agent p 
    ON k.kode_agent = p.kode_agent
  JOIN ms_agent_institusi i
    ON i.kode_institusi = p.kode_institusi 
  JOIN ms_projects j
    ON k.kode_proposal = j.kode_proposal
 WHERE k.status_proposal_id IN(4,8,3,10)
   AND ( i.nama like 'BMT%'
      OR i.nama like 'Baitul Maal Wat%'
      OR i.nama like 'Ksp%' 
       )
 GROUP 
    BY i.nama
     , p.kode_agent;
```